# Where is the error in this integration example?

Tags: integration

I've been practicing calculus recently and found these [example exercises](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/intbypartsdirectory/IntByParts.html).
Please look at problem $19$ which says: 
$$\text{Integrate }\int\frac{x^3}{(x^2+5)^2}  dx.$$
This is the [suggested answer](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/intbypartssoldirectory/IntByPartsSol3.html#SOLUTION%2019) which says that the integral is equal to
$$\frac{x^2}{2(x^2+5)}-\frac{\ln(x^2+5)}{2}.$$

To make sure I am correct I always check with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). To my surprise, the result I got from Wolfram Alpha was different: 
$$\frac{5}{(5 + x^2)} + \frac{\ln(5 + x^2)}{2}.$$

Could someone please help me find the cause of the difference in results? These are by no means the same equations as there is no way to convert one to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in that link link is
$$  - \frac{x^2}{2(x^2+5)}+ \frac 1 2 \ln(x^2+5)$$
which is $-$ times your answer. If you look at the first term, it can be rewritten as 
$$- \frac{x^2}{2(x^2+5)} = - \frac{1}{2 }\left( 1 - \frac{5}{x^2 + 5} \right) = - \frac 1 2 + \frac{5}{2(x^2 + 2)}$$
which only differs from a constant term from answer in W|A. You can assimilate it to constant of integration since it is indefinite integral.

Comment: Thank you, but this is the transition which I do not understand. Could you please expand in a bit more detail on how you achieved it?

Comment: @Macin partial fractions!! take LCM of the latter to get former.

Comment: how $$ \frac{ x^2}{x^2+5} $$ becomes $$ 1 - \frac{5}{x^2 + 5} $$

Comment: it's been a long time since I did it at uni but now had to come back and solve few equations so sorry for questions that may seem stupid. I must be missing something, I know how to make the the former from the latter, but what is the trick to do the opposite? Now I am just plainly curious cos the question is answered ;)

Comment: @Macin haha ... make numerator as $x^2 + 5 - 5$ and split the numerator :P as
$$\frac{x^2 + 5}{x^2 + 5} - \frac{5}{x^2+5}$$

Comment: ok, I feel ashamed, let's pretend I never asked those questions ;) Thank you for such a patience @experimentX $$\frac{x^2+5-5}{x^2+5}$$ is exactly what I needed to see